# Running selenium + nodejs on Docker

Tags: docker, selenium

I have a nodeJS app that starts chrome with chrome-driver and selenium.
I packaged it with Docker, using the following configuration:

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3010
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The issue is, I get the following error from selenium-webdriver when running this docker:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Server terminated early with status 127
```

After quick googling I found out I need chrome, chrome driver and JREinstalled. I have it well configured in my server, but not inside the docker.

I have no idea how to add them to my "node" instance so they can work together.

How I can add chrome, chrome driver, and JRE to my docker?

Comment: Are you running scripts using `Grid`?

Comment: No @NandanA. Is it something I should look for?